# How to get object values from lodash?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

say I have this most basic object

```
var x = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
}
```

if I do this `Object.values(x)` this returns me an array of the values `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

how can I do this in lodash?

I know i can use `get`

`_.get(x)`

is just returning me undefined. I want the same thing as Object.values returns me but using lodash

Comment: Why do you want to use an extra library when it can be handled natively?

Comment: 1) Surely that doesn't matter? its up to me. 2) i need to coz IE cant handle `Object.values()`

Comment: Exactly that was the question, why do you need it, it seems for IE. The question is, how long should one support such an old browser? For the rest, why not [polyfill object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill)

Comment: it's not up to me, how long my company supports browsers for. I agree, i wouldn't like to support it but I have to :). is it not better to import a tiny function from a library that i may reuse elsewhere then a big polyfill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **_.values**

```js
var x = {a: 1,b: 2,c: 3,d: 4};

var result = _.values(x);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take [`_.values`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#values).

```js
var x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

console.log(_.values(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with

```js
var x = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    d: 4
}

const result = _.values(x);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Reference:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#values